# Why isn't my JavaScript printing to my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I learned AngularJS before I learned how to connect vanilla JS to HTML. When I run this code in my browser, the console.logs work, but the number 3 isn't showing up in my first die.

Can you help me fix my code?

JavaScript:
    var roll = document.getElementById('roll');

```
function Dice() {
  Document.write('1');
}

function printNumber() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  one.innterHTML = "3";
  console.log('printNumber called!');
}

roll.onclick = function() {
  printNumber();
  console.log('rolled!');
};
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="dice" id="one">
        </div>
        <div class="dice" id="two">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="button" id="roll">Roll the dice!</div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dice.js"></script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. `Document` should be  `document`. Also, you need to get the `roll` Element. Where did you do that? Never use `document.write()` anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innter should be inner and Document should be document.

```
function Dice() {
  document.write('1');
}

function printNumber() {
  var one = document.getElementById("one");
  one.innerHTML = "3";
  console.log('printNumber called!');
}

roll.onclick = function() {
  printNumber();
  console.log('rolled!');
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I had my console open in Chrome, but no error messages appeared. Can't believe I missed that!